# Fetch image from Rich Text Field via Https

Tags: java, c#, image

I have C# batch which communicate with salesforce objects via SOAP API.
I want to fetch an image which is part of the Rich Text Field in salesforce custom object.
The rich text field himself is Html text and I can get the url of the image tag, but the problem is that the url himself is Https = Http secure connection:

[The url of the image tag:](https://ngam--kerensen.cs17.my.salesforce.com?ec=302&startURL=%2Fcontent%2Fsession%3Furl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fngam--kerensen--c.cs17.content.force.com%252Fservlet%252FrtaImage%253Feid%253Da1Vg0000000lTkK%2526feoid%253D00N20000003jcie%2526refid%253D0EMg00000009N4I)

`https://ngam--kerensen--c.cs17.content.force.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=a1Vg0000000lTkK&feoid=00N20000003jcie&refid=0EMg00000009N4`I

As a result of this, I can't get the resource and write it to a file as a local image for later use.
This is the C# code for fetching the image:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
bool answer = response.ContentType.StartsWith("image", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
 if ((response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK ||
                    response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Moved ||
                    response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect)&&
                    response.ContentType.StartsWith("text/html", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)){
   // if the remote file was found, download it
     using (Stream inputStream = response.GetResponseStream())
     using (Stream outputStream = File.OpenWrite(filepath))
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                        int bytesRead;

                        logger.InfoFormat("Writing to file, filepath:{0}", filepath);
                        do
                        {
                            bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            logger.InfoFormat("bytesRead: {0} ", bytesRead);
                            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        } while (bytesRead != 0);
                        //TODO outputStream.Close();

                    }
                    return true;

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.ErrorFormat("Failed to download {0} to {1} : {2}",
                    uri, filepath, ex.Message);
                logger.Debug("Failed to download " + uri, ex);
            }

            return false;
```

I know that the secure url using java servlet for exposing the image to the world.
The problem is that I can't get the image data and always get the following respond:

```
<script>
if (this.SfdcApp && this.SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator) { SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator.handleRedirect('https://ngam--kerensen.cs17.my.salesforce.com?ec=302&startURL=%2Fcontent%2Fsession%3Furl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fngam--kerensen--c.cs17.content.force.com%252Fservlet%252FrtaImage%253Feid%253Da1Vg0000000lTkK%2526feoid%253D00N20000003jcie%2526refid%253D0EMg00000009N4I'); }  else 
if (window.location.replace){ 
window.location.replace('https://ngam--kerensen.cs17.my.salesforce.com?ec=302&startURL=%2Fcontent%2Fsession%3Furl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fngam--kerensen--c.cs17.content.force.com%252Fservlet%252FrtaImage%253Feid%253Da1Vg0000000lTkK%2526feoid%253D00N20000003jcie%2526refid%253D0EMg00000009N4I');
} else {;
window.location.href ='https://ngam--kerensen.cs17.my.salesforce.com?ec=302&startURL=%2Fcontent%2Fsession%3Furl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fngam--kerensen--c.cs17.content.force.com%252Fservlet%252FrtaImage%253Feid%253Da1Vg0000000lTkK%2526feoid%253D00N20000003jcie%2526refid%253D0EMg00000009N4I';
} 
</script>
```

Any suggestion how to get the actual image data from the Rich Text Area field.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?